# Android Studio: How do I remove the phone border frame on layout previews?

Tags: android, android-layout, border, device

When previewing a layout, such as activity_main.xml on the design view, how do I remove the frame of the phone on my previews? I know this question may have been answered before, but I can't find the solution anywhere.

[image]

I want to remove the black border frame of the phone on my layout preview.

Comment: Uh, that's not a "black border" per se in such a way that there's going to be a border when you deploy it to a device. That's the side of the emulator device.

Comment: Yes, I know it wont be there when I deploy it on a device. It's just annoying because it takes up space on my IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click that `setting button` then **uncheck** the `include Device Frame.`

[image]
[image]

**Update:**
**For Android studio 2.2**  [**See this thread.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460227/android-studio-designer-preview-how-to-include-device-frame/43132508#43132508)

Comment: @Sohail, I'm using 2.2.2 on a mac but I see no settings button that show "include device frames" as an option, where can I find it? thx

Comment: @Sohail  for android studio 2.2 and above follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460227/android-studio-designer-preview-how-to-include-device-frame/43132508#43132508