# How to remove phone border in preview design Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, screen

In the last few days I have started learning Android Studio.
After I installed the program I have faced my first problem.
On the Design window of the xml file, I can see only the screen itself and not the whole border of the phone I'm "testing".

I have seen a simmilar post in this forum but unfortunately I couldn't find the settings button to change this option on the new version of the Android Studio I have installed.

My design screen: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRMUQ.png)

The design screen I would like to see:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzri6.png)

The post I have written about: 
[Android Studio: How do I remove the phone border frame on layout previews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38759082/android-studio-how-do-i-remove-the-phone-border-frame-on-layout-previews)

Thank you!